# Can't fully hide android material card background

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-cardview, materialcardview

Image [how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcOth.png)

Can't fully hide android material card background. I have searched and watched all videos available but nothing has worked so far. I know I could just put something to fill the card but I want to know just in case.

The code:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
android:id="@+id/card"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:backgroundTint="#40000000"
android:clickable="true"
app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Planner"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:fontFamily="@font/nova_bold"/>

<ImageView
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:padding="1dp"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plan_vec" />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: can you please explain what is excelity issue ?

Comment: try ->  cardBackgroundColor instance of background or backgrounTint app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"

Comment: Yh I have tried all that. When I change the opacity of the colour, the issue in the image happens but when the opacity is at 100, it just fills the card. I want the back of the card to be the same as the bothers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use   in your XML   `app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/yourColor"`
or in your java code `card.setCardBackgroundColor(YourColor);` instead of the default `setBackgroundColor()`

**UPDATE**

for the opacity change `android:backgroundTint="#40000000"` by         `android:alpha="0.4"`

Comment: Yh it works when the card doesn't have opacity set on it but when I set opacity the borders and the back do not blend as the image shows

Comment: the opacity is this ? `android:backgroundTint="#40000000"`?

Comment: Yes that was it. I am now using app:cardBackgroundColor="#40000000" the initial 40 means 40% opacity

Comment: But the issue remains the same.

Comment: if I understood correctly you can use `android:alpha="0.4f"`   instead of 
           `android:backgroundTint="#40000000"`

Comment: It works...kind of. it just makes the whole card transparent but I will figure out a way. Thanks.

Comment: sorry isn't float use 0.4 instead of 0.4f